# Why Does the Volume Change When Using Split Coil

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, pick-ups

I have a couple of guitars that have split coil capabilities and when I use the split coil feature, I notice that the volume seems to go down drastically. I'm not entirely sure if it's actually the volume that goes down or just the change in tone that makes it seem like the volume decreased. As the title suggests my question is: why does it seem like this happens?

Comment: I'd say getting a quieter, cleaner, thinner sound is precisely the point of using a coil split, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using both coils, the signals induced the two coils are added together, so the total output power ends up being a bit less than double the output of just one coil.

Comment: @drg Maybe a compressor or boost pedal would help.

Comment: It's the nature of the beast. Like using two mics, then turning one off. Compensation is by using the volume control.